# Updating data inside Listview rows to database table not working

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, ado.net, sql-update

Basically I have bind `Listview` from existing database with editable `textboxes`. & I have two different buttons for Update that data. I have made below method to update `listview` data & calling this method on `button` click. Method `gets` called for both `buttons` but problem is data gets updated on only one `button`. How it is possible if both button calls same method then how it can work for only once button.

e.g.

> Button1 - calls updateExistingAirContract
>
> Button2 - calls updateExistingAirContract

Suppose I change any value of `textbox` & calls this method then it should take values which I have put not the old one. On button1 click it is taking value which i put & on button2 click still taking old values. Below is my method.

```
private void updateExistingAirContract()
{
    if (airContractsList.Items.Count > 0) {
        try {
            foreach (ListViewDataItem item in airContractsList.Items) {
                CheckBox chkAirList = item.FindControl("chkAirList") as CheckBox;
                TextBox airOriginList = item.FindControl("airOriginList") as TextBox;
                TextBox airDestinationList = item.FindControl("airDestinationList") as TextBox;
                TextBox flightNoList = item.FindControl("flightNoList") as TextBox;
                TextBox airServiceTypeList = item.FindControl("airServiceTypeList") as TextBox;
                TextBox airWeightList = item.FindControl("airWeightList") as TextBox;
                TextBox airRateList = item.FindControl("airRateList") as TextBox;

                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE contracts SET origin = @origin, destination = @destination, vehicleNo = @vehicleNo, serviceType = @servicetype, weight = @weight, rate = @rate, contractFrom = @contractFrom, contractTo = @contractTo, creditPeriod = @creditPeriod WHERE ID = @ID";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@origin", airOriginList.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destination", airDestinationList.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicleNo", flightNoList.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serviceType", airServiceTypeList.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", airWeightList.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", airRateList.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contractFrom", contractFrom.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contractTo", contractTo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creditPeriod", contractFrom.Text + " - " + contractTo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", chkAirList.ToolTip);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            bindAirContractsLists();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I have place breakpoint in this method & can see the values of textbox.

Comment: Can u explain with more i didn't understand

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns a value.  If it's greater than zero, it worked.  Your @ID is in the chkAirList.ToolTip???  Every field in your table is a Text field?  Seems odd for something like weight and rate.